# How do you divide a tensor based on its content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a tensor that looks like this:

```
arr = tf.convert_to_tensor([[3, 1],
                            [6, 2],
                            [1, 1],
                            [3, 0],
                            [5, 1],
                            [1, 0],
                            [4, 2]])
```

And I need to compute the average of the first elements of each cell only when the second element is equal to 1. So in this example I would select the cells `[3, 1], [1, 1], [5, 1]` and calculate `average(3, 1, 5)=3`.
Then, I need to repeat this operation for the cells ending with 0 and then 2, and sum up all the averages.

I am writing this as a component for a loss function in a Neural Network, so I need to do this operation using only TensorFlow functions. I have solved this problem in Numpy, and it looks like this:

```
means_sum = sum([np.mean(np.extract(arr.transpose()[1] == rank, arr.transpose()[0])) for rank in [0, 1, 2]])
```

But I can't find a way to do it in TensorFlow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to

1. write a conditional statement for matching second indices of each element..
   I would try `tf.gather` and `tf.not_equal` (or equivalent functions) to filter the matching elements that return a matrix of the same shape as the input in (0,1) values and then multiply by elements to filter the input
2. average the elements by first index (`tf.reduce_mean` should suffice)